# Swift: Error when trying to access a class method through a shared instance

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, tvos

```
class MoviesViewController5: UIViewController {
     static let sharedInstance: MoviesViewController5 = MoviesViewController5()
  
    func fillPage2(menuId menuId:String) {
        // ...
     }
}
```

When I try to access fillPage2 like this:

```
class TabsBarController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let tab4ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(identifier: "MoviesViewController5") as! MoviesViewController5
        // Add each ViewController to your viewControllers array
        
        // This throws an error
        tab4ViewController.sharedInstance.fillPage2(menuId: "2")
        // Static member 'sharedInstance' cannot be used on instance of type 'MoviesViewController5'
    }
    
}
```

This is the error:

> Static member 'sharedInstance' cannot be used on instance of type
> 'MoviesViewController5'

tab4ViewController will actually represent the view. So I need to call the `fillPage2` method on it.
**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: tab4ViewController.sharedInstance.fillPage2(menuId: "2") should be `MoviesViewController5.sharedInstance.fillPage2(menuId: "2")` but I think the main problem here is that you are using sharedInstance here at all like this view controller is some kind of singleton. So most likely the solution is to skip sharedInstance altogether. So the code should be `tab4ViewController.fillPage2(menuId: "2")`

Comment: tab4ViewController.fillPage2(menuId: "2") did the job. Thank you.